# Parsing debuginfo from dalvikvm (Android) in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms, backtrace

I'm making a small Android-app in Eclipse that uses SQLite. It works quite well. When I out of the curiosity browsed through Logcat for some messages, I found repetives of these:

```
06-03 18:40:26.721: INFO/dalvikvm(697): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43ba3230 on audiovideo that has not been deactivated or closed
```

Googling around I found that the error is caused by me forgetting a `cursor.close()`. However, for future reference, how can I get DDMS/Logcat tell me *which* cursor this error is about? At this point I know which it is (I manually searched all the source code), but as my code grows bigger it would be nice to let DDMS point me in a direction where I can extract data. As for now, everything that's dumped in the debug-info window is uncomprehensible for me.

Comment: I still haven't found any solution for this question, and I still stumble upon these logs.